# Append each item of arrays to a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 4 different arrays with the same count of elements. I want to add each element of each array into a new array. For example: `$id_array[0]` should be added into `$artikel_combined`. Then `$name_array[0]` into `$artikel_combined`. And so on. Then when all 4 arrays are done with `index 0`, then they should start with `index 1` and so on.

I tried with this code but it just combines all the arrays, but not what i want.

```
// LoadIni creates an array every nth line.
$id_array = $ini_obj->LoadIni($f_art, 0, 9, 999);
$name_array = $ini_obj->LoadIni($f_art, 1, 9, 999);
$x_array = $ini_obj->LoadIni($f_art, 2, 9, 999);
$y_array = $ini_obj->LoadIni($f_art, 4, 9, 999);

// This is the point where i fail, because it just combines and I'm out of ideas
$arr = array_merge($id_array, $name_array, $x_array, $y_array);
$artikel_combined = [];

// Removing new Lines from the elements
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $artikel_combined[] = trim($item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the array have always the same count of elements you can cycle through them and add them together.

like

```
$count = count($id_array);
$artikel_combined = [];

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $artikel_combined[$i][] = id_array[$i];
    $artikel_combined[$i][] = trim(name_array[$i]);
    $artikel_combined[$i][] = trim(x_array[$i]);
    $artikel_combined[$i][] = trim(y_array[$i]);
}
```

probably not the best way to solve the problem, but it should do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php): *"Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one."*

But you want to join up the same array key for every array into a new array, resulting in a multidimensional array.

You could also do so using [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) passing `null` as the first parameter:

```
// LoadIni creates an array every nth line.
$id_array = $ini_obj->LoadIni($f_art, 0, 9, 999);
$name_array = $ini_obj->LoadIni($f_art, 1, 9, 999);
$x_array = $ini_obj->LoadIni($f_art, 2, 9, 999);
$y_array = $ini_obj->LoadIni($f_art, 4, 9, 999);

$artikel_combined = array_map(null, $id_array, $name_array, $x_array, $y_array);
```